# VMware Network Editor Not working on Ubuntu 17.10 Artful

Tags: networking, permissions, vmware, 17.10

I Installed the latest version of VMware Workstation on ubuntu.17.10
VMware-Workstation-Full-14.0.0-6661328.x86_64.bundle
everything is working fine but whenever i try to open 
Wmware Netwrok Editor

1/ Opening Vmware Network Editor from Vmware Workstation 
 it asks for root password after typing it nothing shows up

2/ Opening Vmware Network Editor from Terminal
sudo /usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-netcfg

i get this screen

No protocol specified

xcb_connection_has_error() returned true

Home directory not accessible: Permission denied

No protocol specified

xcb_connection_has_error() returned true

Home directory not accessible: Permission denied

[AppLoader] Use shipped Linux kernel AIO access library.

An up-to-date "libaio" or "libaio1" package from your system is preferred.

No protocol specified

** (vmware-netcfg:5047): WARNING **: Could not open X display

No protocol specified

(vmware-netcfg:5047): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you ever figure out the solution?